# Linear Search Recursive Runtime

Tags: closed-form, recursive-algorithms

Assume this is the pseudocode of a Linear Search: 
`LS(Array, i, obj)
    if i == Array 
        return false
    else
        return Array[i] == obj or LS(Array, i+1, obj)`
 
For $i = len(A) - n$ Wouldn't the $T(n)$ be: 
$$
T(n) =
\begin{cases} 
  1 & n=0 \\
  1 + T(n+1) & n > 0
   \end{cases}
$$
And how would you find its closed form?

Answer (score 1):

One mistake, $T$ is based on size of the remaining input, so the recurrence should be
$$
T(n) =
\begin{cases} 
      1 & n=0 \\
      1 + T(n-1) & n > 0
   \end{cases}
$$